# Accessing a random index of an incomplete array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which can have a max length of several hundred thousand rows.  It looks like this:

```
arr[12]   = false
arr[334]  = true
arr[753]  = true
arr[1001] = false
arr[1222] = true
```

and so on...

I want to find the fastest way to randomly select the index of a row that is true...

My initial attempt was to do this:

```
for(k in arr) {
 if(arr[k]) {
  candidate.push(k);
 }
}

return Math.floor(Math.random() * candidate.length);
```

But it is quite slow.

Is there a better way to do it?

Ty

Comment: Is `arr` really an array or an object? `for..in` is several times slower than a "normal" `for` loop.

Comment: It is built as an array but not sure if JavaScript will internally turn it into an object.#

Comment: If you defined it as array, then it will be an array ;) Why is your array incomplete? Maybe using another data structure might be better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fraction of missing elements is sufficiently small it will be fast enough to just generate random indexes until you get a hit. Give it a try.

```
var chose_true = function(array) {
    while (true) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
        if (array[index]) {
            return array[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens if we have 10000 falses and 1 true? :D

Comment: Also, what happens if you have a huge gap in the indexes.

Comment: I don't think that should matter, as long as the overall ratio isn't like 500 false to 1 true.

Comment: This would also be my suggestion. If you are concerned about it taking very long when there are only 1 or 2 true values in the array, you could always fall back to @mrwooster's original idea (of searching through the array for true values to choose from) after a predefined number of random stab attempts.

Comment: The array will start empty, random indexes will be added to in in the range 0->~40000, mostly true. As the array fills up, many of the 'true' entries will be replaces with 'false'.  Yep, its a strange data structure.

Comment: @Harikawashi - Interesting idea, to combine both.  When array is small, use my method, as it gets large, use @Jeremy's method.

Comment: @mrwooster If you're constructing it, you may want to just construct the `candidates` array at the same time. If you don't need to regenerate it each time a value is requested, it can be very fast.

Comment: Yes!!!! I could construct the candidate array from all the 'true' values, then pick random candidate values until the candidate array is dry.  Then reconstruct it. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true)
{
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
    if(arr[index])
        return index;
}
```

it is fast if there are a lot of trues and slow if there are a lot of falses but at least its faster then your solution

Comment: I think `candidate.length` is wrong here. And it looks pretty much like  what @Jeremy already posted.

Comment: yeah it looks almost the same.. when i was writing my post there were no answers yet. also @Jeremy is returning the value of the array[index] which is true instead of the index.

Comment: Also slow on sparse arrays: `var arr = []; arr[10000000] = true;`

Comment: Also, this wont work because Math.random() * candidate.length will not return an integer.  Need to add Math.floor around it....

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, there is no pretty way to do this.

The one that i would try to use would be, when you fill the array with true/false elements, push onto an auxiliar structure the indexes of the true values. After that generating a random of those values should be easy enough and you are sure to get a true value on that index.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution would be creating another index for this array:

Each time you modify this array, you rebuild the index of all `true` values into some true_values array. For example:

```
function addNewIndex(key, value) {
   arr[key] = value;
   if (value) {
       true_arr.push(key); //<<<<
   }
}
```

Then simply choose the random element from that index you've built.

Comment: Yes, I would like to be able to do this, but what if I need to change index xxx from true to false? I will have no way of accessing it directly in true_arr...

Answer (score 0):

If this array is going to be changing constantly, and if it is very very big, and if the number of true elements can be very low, how about keeping a list of the True indexes?

When an index becomes true, it is added to the list, when the index is set to false, it is removed from the list, and then you can just choose your index by choosing a random element from the list of true indexes.